# Redis client. How to separate read/write operations?

Tags: redis, haproxy, stackexchange.redis

We use StackExchange.Redis as redis client.

Is it possible to tell the client to use 127.0.0.1: 1001 strictly for Write and 127.0.0.2 strictly for Read?

[image]

Comment: What is the expected behavior when the master node goes belly up or you simply have to reboot it? Also, you won't be able to read your own writes, because the replication is async so it's `network latency between the two hosts + whatever delay is introduced by the async replication`

Comment: When the master goes down, one of the sentinels promotes the new one. As for the latency, it's OK in our scenario.

Answer (score 1):

If your redis server 127.0.0.1:1002 is slaveof 127.0.0.1:1001, then you may execute your 'write' commands like that

```
redisClient.StringSet("key", "value", flags: CommandFlags.DemandMaster);
```

also,  I can notice, that redisClient by it nature will execute commands needs 'write' on master. For 'read' commands you can write

```
redisClient.StringGet("key", flags: CommandFlags.DemandSlave);
```

But if your slave will be unavailable you will get an exception. Another option

```
CommandFlags.PreferSlave
```

from documentation:

> This operation should be performed on the slave if it is available, but will be performed on a master if no slaves are available. Suitable for read operations only.